sp_executesql Not Returning Correct Value Using OUTPUT
The code with sp_executesql is in a loop (two actually), that goes through the list of IDs in the [tmp_compare], and compares the data in each of the columns in the [contact_compare_fields] from two different tables.
The code currently returns in @h_data the column name [Title] instead of the data that is in the table ie 'Chief Financial Officer'
The SQL prints out as:
SELECT @h_dataOUT = SDU_Tools.NULLifBlank(@h_fieldIN) 
FROM [h_processed] 
WHERE CAST(CAST([Contact ID] AS FLOAT) AS BIGINT) = @ziIN;

And if I remove the @h_dataOUT and replace the @h_fieldIN with [Job Title], and @ziIN with the ID to look like this:
SELECT SDU_Tools.NULLifBlank([Job Title]) 
FROM [h_processed] 
WHERE CAST(CAST([Contact ID] AS FLOAT) AS BIGINT) = 1001122877

then it returns the value I am expecting.
Right now I have two sets of these, one for the sf_data, and one for the h_data. They both return the incorrect value right now. The whole process runs REALLY slow (ie 6hr+ for 120k times through the loop), so I am hoping that by fixing this it will speed it up.
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[contact_compare_fields] 
(
    [id]       int identity(1,1),
    [sf_field] varchar(100),
    [h_field]  varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO [contact_compare_fields] 
VALUES
    ('[Title]', '[Job Title]'),
    ('[FirstName]', '[First Name]'),
    ('[LastName]', '[Last Name]'),
    ('[MailingStreet]', '[Person Street]'),
    ('[MailingCity]', '[Person City]'),
    ('[MailingState]', '[Person State]'),
    ('[MailingPostalCode]', '[Person Zip Code]'),
    ('[MailingCountry]', '[Country]')
    
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tmp_compare] 
(
    [id]      int identity(1,1),
    [H_ZI_ID] bigint
)

INSERT INTO [tmp_compare] 
VALUES
    ('1001122877'),('1001125385'),('1002260105'),('100233801'),('1002661679')

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[h_processed] 
(
    [Contact ID] varchar(255),
    [Job Title]  varchar(255)
)

INSERT INTO [h_processed] 
VALUES ('1001122877', 'Chief Financial Officer')

DECLARE
    @zi nvarchar(50) = '',
    @sf_field nvarchar(500) = '',
    @h_field nvarchar(500) = '',
    @sf_data nvarchar(500) = '',
    @h_data nvarchar(500) = '',
    @ParamDef nvarchar(500) = '',
    @sql nvarchar(max)
    
SELECT 
    @sf_field = [sf_field], @h_field = [h_field] 
FROM 
    [contact_compare_fields] 
WHERE 
    [id] = @fld_cnt

SELECT 
    @zi = [H_ZI_ID] 
FROM 
    [tmp_compare] 
WHERE 
    [id] = @cnt

SET @sql = N'SELECT @h_dataOUT = SDU_Tools.NULLifBlank(@h_fieldIN) FROM [h_processed] WHERE CAST(CAST([Contact ID] AS FLOAT) AS BIGINT) = @ziIN;';
SET @ParamDef = N'@h_fieldIN nvarchar(500), @ziIN nvarchar(50), @h_dataOUT varchar(500) OUTPUT';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @ParamDef, @h_fieldIN = @h_field, @ziIN = @zi, @h_dataOUT = @h_data OUTPUT;

PRINT 'h_data:  ' + @h_data


Why are all your parameters defined as an nvarchar and not an appropriate data type? Also, not to mention, CAST(CAST([Contact ID] AS FLOAT) AS BIGINT) has a smell to it; if Contact ID is a meant to be treated as a numerical value, why aren't you storing it as one? If it's not meant to be a numerical value, why are you casting it to one? Either the column and parameter is the wrong data type, or casting shouldn't be there.

In short, your WHERE equates to CAST(CAST([Contact ID] AS FLOAT) AS BIGINT) = CONVERT(bigint,CONVERT(nvarchar(50), tmp_compare.H_ZI_ID))); those converts make very little sense. The table definitions and parameter data types seem to be the real problem.

@ThomA The two tables I am pulling from have them defined as nvarchar so that is what I am using.  However, they will sometimes be converted to scientific notation, so by using the bigint I can avoid that.  While I agree it is annoying, that would not cause the issue I am seeing with the output being incorrect.

Then, if the column is an nvarchar then pass an nvarchar and don't CAST/CONVERT. " However, they will sometimes be converted to scientific notation, " if it'smeant to be an nvarchar then someone isn't passing it nvarchar values.Fix the data and the bad processes that are inserting bad data. There's a multitude of flaws here and stacked together they cause all sorts of problems.

It looks like you are attempting to use dynamic SQL to one of multiple columns based on the selected h_field value from your contact_compare_fields table. You cannot do this with a passed parameter. You must inject the column name directly into the SQL statement:
SET @h_field = REPLACE(REPLACE(@h_field, '[', ''), ']', '') -- unquote
SET @sql = N'
    SELECT @h_dataOUT = SDU_Tools.NULLifBlank(' + QUOTENAME(@h_field) + ')
    FROM [h_processed]
    WHERE CAST(CAST([Contact ID] AS FLOAT) AS BIGINT) = @ziIN;
';

To protect against SQL injection and object names containing spaces or special characters, QUOTENAME() must be used to safely inject names or text values into dynamic SQL. However, your source data already has quoted names in the contact_compare_fields table, so the above code first removes the quoting characters [] before reapplying them using QUOTENAME(). A better approach would be to remove the []s from your contact_compare_fields table.
This will produce SQL that looks like:
    SELECT @h_dataOUT = SDU_Tools.NULLifBlank([Job Title])
    FROM [h_processed]
    WHERE CAST(CAST([Contact ID] AS FLOAT) AS BIGINT) = @ziIN;

When executed, this should produce your desired output: @h_data = 'Chief Financial Officer' instead of just @h_data = '[Job Title]'.
Note that the @h_fieldIN parameter is no longer used and can be dropped as a parameter in the EXEC sp_executesql ... statement.
See this db<>fiddle for a demo
I have not addressed the issues with excessive data conversions. In short, if your ID values are numbers (integers), you should store them using an appropriate type, like BIGINT and consistently treat them as numbers. If your ID values are fixed format text (even if the look like numbers) you should store them as text and consistently treat them as text - don't convert them to numbers for comparisons.

Careful, that's wide upon to injection. You must safely quote injected object names.

@ThomA - Updated. with unquote/requote logic to safely handle the already-quoted names.

Works great.  I did as you suggested and removed the brackets from the list of field names.  I will see if I can do something with the BIGINT mess.

What's funny is I had it working without parameters, but when I tried to make it work "correctly" then it gets messed up :P
